# Error: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, struggeling to get frontend to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting this error when trying to add input from the web-application to the database. Struggeling to understad what the problem is. The error come when the button to insert to the database is used. Here's some of the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductService from './ProductService';


class Input extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
        this.onChangeQuantity = this.onChangeQuantity.bind(this);
        this.onChangePrice = this.onChangePrice.bind(this);
        this.state = {
                id: -1,
                name: null, 
                quantity: null, 
                price: null
        };
    }

    onChangeName(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeQuantity(e) {
        this.setState({
            quantity: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePrice(e) {
        this.setState({
            price: e.target.value
        });
    }

    saveProduct() {
        var data = {
            name: this.state.name, //this is the line witch get the error
            quantity: this.state.quantity,
            price: this.state.price
        };

        ProductService.addProduct(data)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                id: response.data.id,
                name: response.data.name,
                quantity: response.data.quantity,
                price: response.data.price
            });
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    newProduct() {
        this.setState({
            name: "",
            quantity: null,
            price: null
        });
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
          <div id="parent">
            <form>
              <p>Enter name:</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="name"
                required
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onChangeName}
                name="name"
              />
            </form>
            <form>
              <p>Enter price:</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="price"
                required
                value={this.state.price}
                onChange={this.onChangePrice}
                name="price"
              />
            </form>
            <form>
              <p>Enter quantity:</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="quantity"
                required
                value={this.state.quantity}
                onChange={this.onChangeQuantity}
                name="quantity"
              />
            </form>
            <button onClick={this.saveProduct}>Enter in database</button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Input;
```

When i change to for example:

```
saveProduct() {
            var data = {
                name: "test",
                quantity: 123,
                price: 456
            };
```

Everything works. Ive tried diffrent things, but to me the error dont quite make sense. Anyone see where my mistake(s) are? Thank you in advance.

Comment: use saveProduct as an arrow function. The problem is that your function is not getting the class context in the current scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is regarding binding this. As the ReactJS docs state:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
> JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
> bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
> when the function is actually called.

In the constructor just add following line and your code will work:

```
constructor(props) {
    ...
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.saveProduct = this.saveProduct.bind(this);
}
```

Do this for all event handlers. Also read the doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

The properties of 'this' are not always the same.
instead of using this.property. Make a global object (_this) for example and save your data in it, this way you can have your variables and properties in all functions.

for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductService from './ProductService';


class Input extends Component {

let _this = {};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    _this.onChangeName = _this.onChangeName.bind(_this);
    _this.onChangeQuantity = _this.onChangeQuantity.bind(_this);
    _this.onChangePrice = _this.onChangePrice.bind(_this);
    _this.state = {
            id: -1,
            name: null, 
            quantity: null, 
            price: null
    };
}

onChangeName(e) {
    _this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangeQuantity(e) {
    _this.setState({
        quantity: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangePrice(e) {
    _this.setState({
        price: e.target.value
    });
}

saveProduct() {
    var data = {
        name: _this.state.name, //this is the line witch get the error
        quantity: _this.state.quantity,
        price: _this.state.price
    };

    ProductService.addProduct(data)
    .then(response => {
        _this.setState({
            id: response.data.id,
            name: response.data.name,
            quantity: response.data.quantity,
            price: response.data.price
        });
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

newProduct() {
    _this.setState({
        name: "",
        quantity: null,
        price: null
    });
}

render() {
  return (
      <div id="parent">
        <form>
          <p>Enter name:</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            required
            value={_this.state.name}
            onChange={_this.onChangeName}
            name="name"
          />
        </form>
        <form>
          <p>Enter price:</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="price"
            required
            value={_this.state.price}
            onChange={_this.onChangePrice}
            name="price"
          />
        </form>
        <form>
          <p>Enter quantity:</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="quantity"
            required
            value={_this.state.quantity}
            onChange={_this.onChangeQuantity}
            name="quantity"
          />
        </form>
        <button onClick={_this.saveProduct}>Enter in database</button>
      </div>
    );
}
}

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put a bind for saveProduct().
Checkout my minimal working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-wright-jnptu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tretechs arrow function don't have their own 'this' so they use `this` context which is the closest non-arrow parent function.

That is why we need to bind `this` and pass it on to the function. It is good practice to bind callback functions in the contructor function

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
    this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeQuantity = this.onChangeQuantity.bind(this);
    this.onChangePrice = this.onChangePrice.bind(this);
    
    // similarly bind saveProduct
    this.saveProduct = this.saveProduct.bind(this);  }
```